# How to Calculate a particular area using MouseClicked () method in Processing?

Tags: arduino, mouseevent, processing

In my window there is a circle. I have implemented the `void MouseClicked()` method to take effect on the mouse click event. That means only clicking inside the circle should change the color of the circle and do the corresponding operation.

But the problem is wherever I click (even outside the circle), it changes the color of the circle. So I understand that the `mouseClicked()` method isn't stable. How do I fix this?

My code in processing:

```
int colorValue = 0;
void setup() { 
    size(450, 255); 
    background(204);
} 

void draw() {         
    fill(colorValue);
    ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
}
void mouseClicked() {
    if (colorValue == 0) {
        colorValue = 255;
    } else {
        colorValue = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing any check for whether the mouse is in the circle. You could use the `dist()` function to help with that:

```
int colorValue = 0;
float circleX = 56;
float circleY = 46;
float circleR = 55;

void setup() { 
  size(450, 255); 
  background(204);
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
 } 

void draw() {         
   fill(colorValue);
   ellipse(circleX, circleY, circleR, circleR);
}
void mouseClicked() {
   if(dist(mouseX, mouseY, circleX, circleY) < circleR){
      if (colorValue == 0) {
         colorValue = 255;
      } else {
         colorValue = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks you very very much. It answers my question. And YES Happy Halloween.